# Style tab-selected element?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu bar with drop-down sub menus that I've created with CSS. Everything works just fine when I'm using a mouse, but if I use the tab key to select the menu items, the sub menu won't open and I'm unable to go to any of the sub pages without using my mouse.

Is there a way to open the sub menus with the tab key without using JS?

Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLv6LmbL/)

**HTML**

```
<span id="main_menu">
    <span>
        <a href="#">Page 1</a>
    </span>
    <span>
        <a href="#">Page 2</a>
        <span>
            <span>
                <a href="#-history">Sub Page 1</a>
            </span>
            <span>
                <a href="#">Order Savings</a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>    
    <span>
        <a href="#">Page 3</a>
    </span>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
#main_menu{
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

#main_menu > span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#main_menu > span:not(:first-child)::before{
    content: "|";
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 6px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#main_menu a{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main_menu > span > span{
    display: none;
}

#main_menu > span:hover > span,
#main_menu > span:focus > span,
#main_menu > span > span:hover,
#main_menu > span > span:focus{
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#main_menu > span > span > span > a{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 7px;
}

#main_menu > span > span > span > a:hover,
#main_menu > span > span > span > a:focus{
    border-color: #00cc00;
    color: #00aa00;
}
```

Comment: I can't even tab onto that frame

Comment: @Huangism Click on the "Page 1" link, and then you can tab to "Page 2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When tabbing the `focus` goes to the `anchor` element not to the `span`. Updating the CSS rule to use the `a` selector, you get

```
#main_menu > span:hover > span,
#main_menu > a:focus + span > span,
#main_menu > span > span:hover,
#main_menu > span > a:focus + span{
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9j96dnv/).

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. It seems to be working, but I can't tell because once I tab to an item in the sub menu, the sub menu vanishes. Do you know how to keep that from happening? I've tried it in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Nevermind. It's apparently not possible yet, but will be simple once  [`:has()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#relational) from the level 4 CSS selectors sees browser support, which will hopefully be soon.

Comment: Yep. Couldn't find a way to get this working without Javascript. :)